# 3 версии Python на Ubuntu 18.04, как оставить только одну?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.7

всем привет,
насколько я знаю 2.7 идёт по умолчанию и её удалять не рекомендуется.
как atom заставить работать только с 3.7 без создания окружения?
есть ли вариант как-то удалить хирургическим методом неугодные версии(2.7,3.6)?
наставил по глупости - сейчас аукается.

Comment: Насколько я помню, 2.7 как раз НЕ идёт по умолчанию с некоторых пор. 3.6 вы удалить не сможете, потому что на него завязано много системных штук, а 2.7 и 3.7 удаляйте так, как устанавливали

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: Боюсь, как раз наоборот, 2.7 default / Смотрите:  `cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l` и `python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)`

Comment: какой смысл вы вкладываете во фразу «работать только с версией 3.7»? т.е., опишите (прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]), что именно сейчас происходит «не так, как вам надо». от этого напрямую зависит и ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @avp как минимум в серверной убунте python2.7 из коробки вообще не установлен, проверял почти только что (десктопную убунту ещё не проверял). А то, что команда `python` ссылается на `python2.7`, ничего не значит

Comment: Прямо из атома запускаете скрипт? Как я понимаю для этого нужен какой-то доп. пакет? Вот здесь описан способ настройки пакета `script` для работы с python 3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507376/5201699 Может вам будет полезно.

Comment: @avp проверил в свежеустановленной десктопной убунте — python2.7 тоже отсутствует https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Gb5.png

Comment: @andreymal, о чём спор-то? [в репозитории для дистрибутива ubuntu версии 18.04 пакет python имеет в данный момент версию 2.7.15~rc1-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin о том, что 2.7 можно безболезненно удалять)

Comment: @andreymal, при [таком-то списке обратных зависимостей](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pvy7jcTpP9/) определение «безболезненно» выглядит довольно странным.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ни один пакет из перечисленных не предустановлен в системе изначально (даже samba, к моему удивлению) или не имеет 2.7 в списке обязательных. Так что да, удалять можно безболезненно, если ни один из этих пакетов не был установлен вручную для каких-то целей

Answer (score 0):

**Переключение версии Python на Ubuntu и Debian**

Инструмент командной строки **update-alternatives** предназначен для создания и поддержки символических ссылок для команд по умолчанию.

С его помощью мы можем легко переключать команды на разные версии.

В данном учебнике на системе Ubuntu установлены Python3.9 и Python2.7.

Мы создадим группу для обеих команд и установим символические ссылки.

Создайте симлинк из /usr/bin/python2.7 в /usr/bin/python и задайте имя группы как “python”.

Позже имя группы будет использоваться для переключения ссылок.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1 

update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

Измените ссылку симлинка /usr/bin/python3.9 на /usr/bin/python и установите имя группы на “python”.

Имя группы должно быть одинаковым для всех версий python.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 2
```

Вывод:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.9 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

Повторите шаг 2, чтобы добавить в группу еще одну версию Python, которая уже установлена в вашей системе.

На данном этапе вы добавили два бинарника python в группу с именем “python”.

Теперь вы можете легко переключиться на любую версию с помощью следующих команд.

Здесь “python” – это имя группы, определенное в приведенных выше командах.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Вывод: [Выберите опцию]

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         manual mode

Press to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

В приведенном выше выводе Python 2.7 установлен в качестве текущей версии.

Чтобы изменить ее на Python 3.9, нужно ввести 0 или 2 и нажать Enter.

Вот и все.

Текущая версия Python в вашей системе изменена.

Просто введите следующую команду для просмотра корректной активной версии Python

```
python -V
```

Вывод:

```
Python 3.9.2
```

Вы можете добавить несколько версий Python в группу (Шаги: 01 и 02) и легко переключаться между ними.

**Заключение**

В этом руководстве вы узнали о переключении версий Python по умолчанию в системах Ubuntu и Debian Linux.

Вместо переключения версий вы также можете настроить виртуальную среду Python для своих приложений.